# Select maximum 4 images on UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

If user select more then 4 images then display alert box.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *secell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.row == 4) {


        UIAlertView * alert =[[UIAlertView alloc ] initWithTitle:@"OK Dailog"
                                                         message:@"This is OK dialog"
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                               otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    else
    {
        UIImageView *imgselect = (UIImageView *)[secell viewWithTag:110];
        imgselect.image = [UIImage  imageNamed:@"selectimg.png"];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of checking the  `indexPath.row` you should check the number of selected items. can try something like this

```
NSArray *selectedIndexPaths =  [collectionView  indexPathsForSelectedItems];

if (selectedIndexPaths.count > 4)
{
   // Show alert
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should be set in delegate method `collectionView:shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath`

```
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    BOOL shouldSelect = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems.count < 4;
    if (!shouldSelect) {
        // Show Alert
    }
    return shouldSelect;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for swift 5

```swift
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        let shouldSelect = (collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.count ?? 0) < 4
        if !shouldSelect {
            // show alert here
        }
        return shouldSelect
    }
```